# Scrape selected item, in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

Hi I would like to scrape the selected item in node.js well it might be better if I can search for the text then grab the value from there.

Here is the info I am using

Link: https://kith.com/collections/footwear/products/jbaq4160-140

What I want to grab

I want to grab only the **value** part.

```
<option selected="selected" data-sku="888407130724" value="12572472705093">4.5</option>
```

What I've tried.
I've watched 2 hours of cherrio youtube tutorials but they only work by grabbing the class which in this case I need to find the value based on a text (4.5). So really I am lost, I a cannot find it using a class I need to find using text (4.5) I dont even think I would need to use cherrio let me know.

Updated Code:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');



request('https://kith.com/collections/footwear/products/jbaq4160-140', (error, response, html) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
const $ = cheerio.load(html);

  const output = $(':contains("4.5")').attr('value');

  console.log(output);
  console.log('done');
}

  });
```

Nothing shows in up in the log.

Comment: I would suggest using a javascript debugger to inspect your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would use the :contains pseudo:

```
$(':contains("4.5")').attr('value')
```

Comment: I updated my code please check it now, no console log is working for some reason.

Comment: That page uses javascript, you're going to need regex + json for that.